# P/Invoke. How to call unmanaged method with marshalling from C#?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, marshalling, intptr

I've got a problem with P/Invoke. I'm calling .dll (implemented on c++) from c# code. There is a class, that contains the next methods:

```
virtual AudioFileList *API  CreateAudioFileList ()=0;
virtual bool API  DisposeAudioFileList (AudioFileList *iAudioFileList)=0;
```

**`AudioFileList`** class looks like:

```
virtual bool API  GetFile (long index, std::string *oPath, AudioFileInfo *fileInfo)=0;
virtual long API  GetNumberFiles ()=0;
```

So, the question is how can I call ***`CreateAudioFileList`***  method and than pass the result to ***`DisposeAudioFileList`*** from C# code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, due to name mangling.  You should invest in learning C++/CLI.  This will allow you to create an intermediary layer that provides proper marshaling and isn't inhibited by name mangling in C++.

Here's what it might look like in C++/CLI (untested, of course):

### .h

```
public ref class ManagedAudioFileList
{
private:
    const AudioFileList* Native;
    // Replace AudioFileListManager with the class containing
    // the CreateAudioFileList and DisposeAudioFileList methods.
    const AudioFileListManager* Manager;

public:
    ManagedAudioFileList(void);
    !ManagedAudioFileList(void);
    ~ManagedAudioFileList(void);
    // Insert various methods exposed by AudioFileList here.
};
```

### .cpp

```
ManagedAudioFileList::ManagedAudioFileList(void)
{
    // Replace AudioFileListManager with the class containing the
    // CreateAudioFileList and DisposeAudioFileList methods.
    Manager = new AudioFileListManager();
    Native = Manager->CreateAudioFileList();
}

~ManagedAudioFileList::ManagedAudioFileList()
{
    Manager->DisposeAudioFileList(Native);
    delete Manager;
}

!ManagedAudioFileList::ManagedAudioFileList()
{
}

// Wrap various methods exposed by AudioFileList.
```

Comment: Just want you know that those two functions are pure virtual functions which are not exported in the C++ DLL. Your reason of "You can't, due to name mangling" is incorrect.

Comment: @dave You're partially right. The reasons are a lot more complex than name mangling, but "why" doesn't really contribute to the answer, so I didn't bother explaining. Virtual methods--not just pure virtual methods--won't function as intended if called directly.  Pure virtual methods don't exist at all in their abstract classes, at least in the traditionally invocable sense.  That being said, their specific implementations still have addresses, can technically still be exported, and could theoretically be called rather hackishly via P/Invoke. At that point, name mangling would be negligible.

Comment: very good point. You do know you can call C++ class method including virtual methods from C# via P/Invoke.

Comment: @dave It's theoretically possible, but hackish, compiler-dependent, and generally a bad idea.

Comment: It is a C++ dll. Any C++ DLL is compiler-dependent. Your C++/CLI solution is actually based on this idea.

Answer (score 1):

I use this all the time to generate my static extern malarkey

http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120

Comment: There's an automated tool for that?  Awesome find!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to call the classes in a native C++ DLL module through P/Invoke. Yet there's Visual C++ Team Blog post with a [solution](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9729423), but it is complicated.

There's one more link you might find useful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/5df04db1-bbc8-4389-b752-802bc84148fe/

Answer (score 1):

This article on CodeProject explains how to deal with this sort of marshalling.

[How to Marshal a C++ Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class)